# does not have a member called dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift, cell, reuseidentifier

I cant make my code work properly, it keeps saying "UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection: int) -> Int' does not have a member named 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier'" [image]

Would be happy if someone could explain this :)

Here's my swift file:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var mySecondTableView: UITableView!

var secondArrayOfDisplays: [secondDisplayName] = [secondDisplayName] ()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.setUpDisplays()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func setUpDisplays()
{
    var display1  = secondDisplayName(secondName: "8 Inch STD Widescreen", secondImageName: "8 Inch Widescreen.png")
    var display2  = secondDisplayName(secondName: "12 Inch MMD", secondImageName: "12 inch mmd.png")
    var display3  = secondDisplayName(secondName: "12 Inch STD", secondImageName: "12 inch std.png")
    var display4  = secondDisplayName(secondName: "13 Inch STD Widescreen", secondImageName: "13 inch std.png")
    var display5  = secondDisplayName(secondName: "15 Inch MMD", secondImageName: "15 inch mmd.png")
    var display6  = secondDisplayName(secondName: "15 Inch STD", secondImageName: "15 inch std.png")
    var display7  = secondDisplayName(secondName: "17 Inch MMD", secondImageName: "17 inch mmd.png")
    var display8  = secondDisplayName(secondName: "17 Inch STD", secondImageName: "17 inch std.png")
    var display9  = secondDisplayName(secondName: "19 Inch MMD", secondImageName: "19 inch mmd.png")
    var display10 = secondDisplayName(secondName: "19 Inch STD", secondImageName: "19 inch std.png")
    var display11 = secondDisplayName(secondName: "24 Inch MMD Widescreen", secondImageName: "24 inch mmd.png")
    var display12 = secondDisplayName(secondName: "24 Inch STD Widescreen", secondImageName: "24 inch std.png")
    var display13 = secondDisplayName(secondName: "26 Inch MMD Widescreen", secondImageName: "26 inch mmd.png")
    var display14 = secondDisplayName(secondName: "26 Inch STD Widescreen", secondImageName: "26 inch std.png")

    secondArrayOfDisplays.append(display1)
    secondArrayOfDisplays.append(display2)
    secondArrayOfDisplays.append(display3)
    secondArrayOfDisplays.append(display4)
    secondArrayOfDisplays.append(display5)
    secondArrayOfDisplays.append(display6)
    secondArrayOfDisplays.append(display7)
    secondArrayOfDisplays.append(display8)
    secondArrayOfDisplays.append(display9)
    secondArrayOfDisplays.append(display10)
    secondArrayOfDisplays.append(display11)
    secondArrayOfDisplays.append(display12)
    secondArrayOfDisplays.append(display13)
    secondArrayOfDisplays.append(display14)
}

func secondTableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return secondArrayOfDisplays.count
}

func secondTableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
{
    let secondCell: SecondCustomCellTableViewCell =
    secondTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as SecondCustomCellTableViewCell

    let secondDisplay = secondArrayOfDisplays[indexPath.row]
    secondCell.setSecondCell(secondDisplay.secondName, imageName: secondDisplay.secondImageName)

    secondCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

    return secondCell
}

func secondTableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let secondDisplay = secondArrayOfDisplays[indexPath.row]

    var SecondDetailedViewController: SecondDetailViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondDetailViewController") as SecondDetailViewController

    SecondDetailedViewController.secondNameString = secondDisplay.secondName
    SecondDetailedViewController.mySecondDetailedImageName = secondDisplay.secondImageName

    self.presentViewController(SecondDetailedViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong variable when you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`:

```
secondTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as SecondCustomCellTableViewCell
```

`secondTableView` is a function pointer.

Instead, you want to use the `tableView` that was passed to your function:

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as SecondCustomCellTableViewCell
```